# Query Stack Overflow on how many days someone has been banned?

Tags: support, data-explorer, account-suspension

Maybe I missed it but, there does not seem to be a way to create a query on [Query Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) for how many days someone has been banned since becoming a member.

Any way to do this?

Comment: While you can find [possible current suspended users from SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/861087) (or do a lengthy scan [on the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#order=asc&min=1&max=1&sort=reputation&inname=common&filter=!T6o4.FgytS2UZFAsYW&site=stackoverflow&run=true)) there is no option to look into the history nor is [that wanted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293213/) and there are even calls to [remove the SEDE loophole to find suspended users at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Bans are meant to be served for as long as the term specifies, then when the person is *un*banned, they are welcomed back with a clean slate.  No data in SEDE <s>exists</s> should exist about when a user was banned or why.

For reference, check out [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

Comment: I don't think it is a clean slate ,b/c each successive ban increases in time not allowed on the site???

Comment: If the behavior persists for a user (e.g. they were banned [from review] for poor reviews, and they *kept* reviewing poorly), then it makes sense for it to increase since the perpetrator hasn't demonstrated an improvement in behavior.  Those situations are fairly rare as I understand it, as only a handful of repeat offenders persist (and/or talk about it on Meta or other social media).

Comment: So, data does exist on user bans? If so, omitting reasons for the ban, could you not have a way to query how long or how many times someone has been banned?

Comment: @KyloRen The point, I believe, is that that is between the user and the mods, and only comes into play if further ban-worthy offences happen.

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong.  Data *definitely* exists.  It's just not in the hands of mere mortals like you or I.

Comment: OK, I see now..